# A WinJS SDK which breaks all jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sdk, winjs

I wanted to include a WinJS SDK from a third party into my electron app. However, I'm very confused because the script itself doesn't seem to be valid Javascript code, it's missing semicolons and stuff. I checked it on https://jshint.com/  and my concerns are proved.

**Here is an example from the file:**

```
function _0x296fx4(_0x296fx1) {
  if (!_0x296fx7a[_0x296fx1]) {
    var _0x296fx2 = _0x296fx8[_0xbe69[4]],
      _0x296fx5 = _0x296fx19(_0xbe69[6] + _0x296fx1 + _0xbe69[7])[_0xbe69[5]](_0x296fx2),
      _0x296fx6 = _0x296fx5[_0xbe69[9]](_0xbe69[8]);
    _0x296fx5[_0xbe69[10]]();
    if (_0x296fx6 === _0xbe69[11] || _0x296fx6 === _0xbe69[12]) {
      _0x296fx7b || (_0x296fx7b = _0x296fx8[_0xbe69[14]](_0xbe69[13]), _0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[15]] = _0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[16]] = _0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[17]] = 0), _0x296fx2[_0xbe69[18]](_0x296fx7b);
      if (!_0x296fx7c || !_0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[14]]) {
        _0x296fx7c = (_0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[20]] || _0x296fx7b[_0xbe69[21]])[_0xbe69[19]], _0x296fx7c[_0xbe69[26]]((_0x296fx19[_0xbe69[23]][_0xbe69[22]] ? _0xbe69[24] : _0xbe69[12]) + _0xbe69[25]), _0x296fx7c[_0xbe69[27]]()
      };
      _0x296fx5 = _0x296fx7c[_0xbe69[14]](_0x296fx1), _0x296fx7c[_0xbe69[4]][_0xbe69[18]](_0x296fx5), _0x296fx6 = _0x296fx19[_0xbe69[9]](_0x296fx5, _0xbe69[8]), _0x296fx2[_0xbe69[28]](_0x296fx7b)
    };
    _0x296fx7a[_0x296fx1] = _0x296fx6
  };
  return _0x296fx7a[_0x296fx1]
}
```

Is this normal Javascript or something else? The strange part is, that this script actually works! But for some reason, it breaks the all jQuery plugins in my app like jQuery UI.

**What should I do to get it to work with the jQuery plugins?**

Comment: Know that javascript does not necessarily need semi-colons in most cases, because of [asi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Comment: But my console does still notice these things.

Comment: _Your console_ ... or JSHint? ... anyway, even [jshint has options to reduce those messages](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi)

Comment: I meant the chrome console in electron

Comment: I ended up throwing the jquery stuff out. Now it's working